# Как правильно работать с AntiGate?

Tags: api, распознавание-символов, java

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема: нашёл API для работы с AntiGate, но каждый раз получаю неверную разгадку.

Код:

```
        AntigateClient client = AntigateClientBuilder.create()
                .setKey("6vmpilt0prkawn0mscnzvq6jqhibcgyp").build();
        // Проверка баланса
        double balance = client.getBalance();
        // Загрузка капчи
        String id = client.upload("C:\\index.png");
        CaptchaStatus cs = client.checkStatus(id);
        if (cs.isReady()) {
            String text = cs.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
```

Пример капчи:

http://i65.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0831/30/8a8f25599cfa10ae5c8651fff3373b30.jpeg

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможно, у вас просто сложные капчи. Попробуйте включить [функцию двойного распознавания](http://antigate.com/panel.php?action=100sure).

Comment: Эх,если бы это был мой кей...

Answer (score 1):

Давно пользуюсь хорошей библиотекой - [Antigate.NET](http://l2-ip.com/antigate.net/). Вроде бы даже указана у Antigate'а на оф. сайте.
В общем, категорически советую.
Разгадывает верно, есть функционал исключений и обратной связи при неверном разгадывании капчи.